# Can DeepFace verify() accept an image array or PIL Image object?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, verify

My DeepFace Implementation

```
def verify(img, frame, model):
    results= DeepFace.verify(img, frame, enforce_detection=False, model_name=model)
    print("result: ", results)
    verification= results['verified']
    if verification is True:
        print(model, "Successfully recognised. SCORE=")
        return
    return
```

I am trying to pass a PIL Image instead of "*.jpg" to verify() function but it gives error

```
    raise ValueError("Invalid arguments passed to verify function: ", instance)
ValueError: ('Invalid arguments passed to verify function: ', <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=160x160 at 0x7F4D5D03FBE0>)
```

I want to ask is there any way I can pass directly PIL Image object or image array without saving it to disk prior?

What I am passing:

```
picture= "extracted_face_picture/single_face_picture.jpg"
picture= Image.open(picture)
picture= picture.resize((160,160))

frames_from_npz= "video_faces.npz"
frames= np.load(frames_from_npz)
frames= frames["arr_0"]
i=0
for frames_arr in frames:
    frame= Image.fromarray(frames_arr)

    df.verify(picture,frame, "Facenet")
    print(i, "Above reuslts are for frame", frame_num)
    
    i+= 1
```

**Note that I can still successfully implement DeepFace with saving images in directories then reading them with imread() I only want to know if there are other ways without saving images to disk**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using [this](https://github.com/serengil/deepface) module, the documentation says:

> Herein, face pairs could be exact image paths, numpy array or base64 encoded images

So, presumably, you can make your **PIL Images** into Numpy arrays like this:

```
results = DeepFace.verify(np.array(PILIMAGE), ...)
```

Comment: I did np.array(image_path), but I still getting error "raise ValueError("Face could not be detected ...." ) ,
any suggestion ? please help me , thanks in advance :)

Comment: @NadyrbekSultanov You need `np.array(Image.open(image_path))`

Comment: but if I would like to get image from Image.fromarray() ?

Comment: @NadyrbekSultanov You can use 2 steps. First, you can get a **PIL Image** with `im = Image.open(image_path)` Then, secondly, you can get a **Numpy array** from that **PIL Image** with `na = np.array(im)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot brother, I followed your way and got my results.

For others:
I encountered error again once I followed brother Mark Setchell but it was precisely because I was passing one input as path and other one as numpy array.
If you have to pass numpy array make sure to pass it for both of the input parameters.

```
picture= "extracted_face_picture/single_face_picture.jpg"
picture= Image.open(picture)
.
.
df.verify(picture, np.array(frame), "Facenet")
```

correction:

```
df.verify(np.array(picture),np.array(frame), "Facenet")
```

Thanks a lot brother Mark Setchell.